# how to calculate a gradient on a specific weight manually in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
# a part of my code, it works independently
import torch
class wmodel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Linear(8, 10)
        self.lossfunc = torch.nn.BCELoss()
        self.optimizer = optimizer(self.parameters(), lr=0.2)

rrr = wmodel()
datai = torch.tensor([1.,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
target = torch.tensor([1.,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
qan = rrr.model(datai)
loss = target-qan
```

I'm trying to calculate the loss[0]'s partial derivative to rrr.model.weight[0][0], one of the problem I'm facing is rrr.model.weight[0][0] does not participate in the calculation, which means I can't call grad on it, I'm searching for a variable that actually participated in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be helpful in pinpointing the exact problem if you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, I suspect that it's possible that you're not calling `your_model.backwards()` after calculating your loss. The gradients won't propagate until you call `backwards()`, this is to account for things like RNNs or taking the average gradient over multiple batches. Each time you call `backwards()`, it adds (as in *arithmetic addition*) the new gradient to the gradient currently propagated, until you call `your_model.zero_grad()`, which sets your gradient back to zero.

Comment: It's solved. Linear.weight do participate in the process, I haven't found reason that the grad returns None yet but my code are working now. This is because the issue code was deleted yesterday and the new code I wrote are working. As you see this is my first post. There are some bugs in the code provided above which makes it difficult to understand, my question also isn't clear enough. Thanks for reminding zero_grad since I did forget it. If the problem is solved, am I suppose to do something to the post? Or it's ok to give a "Accept this answer" and leave?

Comment: @mhoofive No problem. If your problem is solved, you don't have to do anything to the post. Accept an answer if it solves your problem, then move on to bigger and better things. :)